# Understanding Spring AOP interceptor overhead

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, aspectj, spring-aop

Alright so I need to migrate some CDI Interceptors to Spring Boot and I've written a simple "proof of concept" test case:

```
package ch.cypherk.myapp.util.aop

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner
import javax.inject.Inject

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
class SimpleInterceptorIT{
    companion object {
        val expectedArg = "Hakuna Matata"
        lateinit var interceptorOutput:String
    }

    @Inject
    private lateinit var client:ClientClass


    @Test
    fun `interceptor works`(){
        client.foo()


        assertThat(interceptorOutput).isEqualTo("ch.cypherk.myapp.util.aop.TargetClass.foo(\"$expectedArg\")")
    }
}
@Component
class TargetClass{
    fun foo(arg:String){
        println("I did something.")
    }
}

@Component
class ClientClass(val target:TargetClass){
    fun foo(){
        target.foo("Hakuna Matata")
    }
}

@Aspect
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
class TestInterceptorConfiguration{

    @Before("execution(* ch.cypherk.myapp.util.aop.TargetClass.*(..))")
    fun intercept(joinPoint:JoinPoint){
        val signature = joinPoint.signature
        println(signature)
        SimpleInterceptorIT.interceptorOutput =
            "${signature.declaringTypeName}.${signature.name}(${
            joinPoint.args
                .map { when(it){
                    is String -> "\"$it\""
                    else -> it
                }}
                .joinToString(",")
            })"
    }
}
```

These are the **ONLY** classes in that package.

Output:

```
void ch.cypherk.myapp.util.aop.TargetClass.foo(String)
I did something.
```

And the test is green.

Now let's widen the search spectrum a bit ...

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
class TestInterceptorConfiguration{

    @Before("execution(* ch.cypherk.myapp.util.aop.*.*(..))")
    fun intercept(joinPoint:JoinPoint){
        val signature = joinPoint.signature
        println(signature)
        SimpleInterceptorIT.interceptorOutput =
            "${signature.declaringTypeName}.${signature.name}(${
            joinPoint.args
                .map { when(it){
                    is String -> "\"$it\""
                    else -> it
                }}
                .joinToString(",")
            })"
    }
}
```

This takes an *ETERNITY* to start.

Yes, the output is

```
void ch.cypherk.myapp.util.aop.ClientClass.foo()
void ch.cypherk.myapp.util.aop.TargetClass.foo(String)
I did something.
```

Yes, the test is green.

Yes, the test *runs* for a as little as `117ms`.

BUT it takes an eternity for Spring to start up.

Why? And more importantly, what can I do about it? Because this is very not ok.

I've taken a look at the `spring-boot-starter-aop` and it defines

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

All of which are -- as you will have noticed -- *compile* scoped.

My expectation was, then, that this would all get weaved at compile time.
That does not seem to be the case. Or if it is, it doesn't stop Spring from doing something weird with the package anyway.

I'd appreciate some help in understanding what's going on, here.

Comment: `<scope>compile</scope>` does only mean that the dependecy must be available at compile time. **Not** that aop is applied when the class is compiled AFAIK

Comment: 1) If you want to have compile time weaving you need to add the aspectj plugin to your pom. 2) Do you see some output in the console? Maybe you should set the log level to debug and check which step is taking long

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Set debug output for what package? If I set `logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG` there are no outputs for the interesting step, there's just a "gap" of a bit over a minute in the debug outputs where I assume it's doing whatever it's doing in AOP.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli actually if I do a 
`logging.level.org=DEBUG`, `logging.level.com=DEBUG`, I get the very (un)interesting outputs `HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)` during that period. No idea what that has to say -- or if at all.

Comment: Can you remove @EnableAspectJAutoProxy and test again?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli already did. Makes no difference, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same as you did and it works fast.

But I have different dependencies.

Can you try with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Edit:

I've run your provided Kotlin code and the output is:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.5.RELEASE)

2019-06-04 17:05:19.411  INFO 19840 --- [           main] c.c.myapp.util.aop.SimpleInterceptorIT   : Starting SimpleInterceptorIT on LAPTOP-FQPHQ5E5 with PID 19840 (started by simon in C:\Users\simon\Workspace\stackoverflow\demo-aop-kotlin)
2019-06-04 17:05:19.411  INFO 19840 --- [           main] c.c.myapp.util.aop.SimpleInterceptorIT   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-06-04 17:05:21.353  INFO 19840 --- [           main] c.c.myapp.util.aop.SimpleInterceptorIT   : Started SimpleInterceptorIT in 2.358 seconds (JVM running for 4.008)
void ch.cypherk.myapp.util.aop.ClientClass.foo()
void ch.cypherk.myapp.util.aop.TargetClass.foo(String)
I did something.
```

No difference between both executions.

Comment: Doesn't change anything, I'm afraid (and I would've been very surprised if it did because your second dependency is already included in the first).

Comment: Strange. Probably it's a Kotlin issue. I will try with Kotlin

Comment: I very much doubt Kotlin is the issue since it's essentially just a different syntax. But please let me know if it does change something. :)

Comment: As I said if tried with Java and have no difference

Comment: I took your Kotlin code an can't see any issues. What other dependencies and code do you have? You mentioned Hikari so you have data access.

Comment: Well, it's a rather large app and we have tons of dependencies. ^^'
But as a workaround, we've created our own annotation and are using THAT to filter rather than specifying packages / classes / methods directly in aspectj. That seems to work ... for now. Thanks, though.

Comment: So if it is a large app are you sure that your aspect only considers the two classes or are there many more ?

Comment: The kotlin file I posted in the question is the only file in the `ch.cypherk.myapp.util.aop` package (in fact, I created it under `src/test` just for this IT). So unless I blundered and `@Before("execution(* ch.cypherk.myapp.util.aop.*.*(..))")` is scanning more than that package, yes, I'm fairly sure these are the only classes considered.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but how i understand the aspectjweaver, introduce advice to Java class at load time

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

compile-time weaving is the simplest approach

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
        <encoding>UTF-8 </encoding>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <!-- use this goal to weave all your test classes -->
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Havent tried it out, but hope this works for you.